# Unparseable date exception using Android platform

Tags: android, date, parse-platform

I am working on Android application in which I am going to send my date to the server. But I am getting the error of "Unparsable date exception", my date is: "3/12/2018".

My code is given below:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
Date parsedDate = sdf.parse(setDateTxt); //setDateTxt returns 3/12/2018 from date picker
SimpleDateFormat print = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
object.put("dateOfBirth", print.format(parsedDate));
```

Comment: "3/12/2018" is not the same date format as "EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy".

Comment: @BilltheLizard kindly suggest me the correction from my given code. It will help me out thanks alot.

Comment: Well do you understand what your current code is doing? What do you expect the `"EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"` to mean? What's its purpose in your code? (*Always* make sure you understand the APIs you're using...)

Comment: If you're getting the text from a date picker, can't you get the same information *not* as text?

Answer (score 0):

the `SimpleDateFormat` has to match your `setDateText` pattern.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: If it's only M, it's probably only d as well.